# First row of column has same height as text in a multirow column

Tags: verbatim, multirow

In this example, why is the lorem1 cell three lines long ... corresponding to the 3 lines in verbatim? How can I get the two lorem rows to be of equal height? Thanks in advance!

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{9cm}|c|p{6cm}|}
\hline

\multirow{4}{*}

\scriptsize
\begin{verbatim}
a
b
c
\end{verbatim} 

& lorem1 & lorem1 \\ \cline{2-3}

& lorem2 & lorem2 \\ \cline{2-3}
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

[image: output]

Comment: please always post complete document so people can reproduce the problem and test answers, but the input looks in error to me, the spanning text should be the third argument to `\multirow` (so the argument is just `\par` here) as an argument it can then not include verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, array}

\newsavebox{\verbbox}

\begin{document}

\sbox{\verbbox}{%
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{verbatim}
a
b
c
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}%
}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|c|p{3cm}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\usebox{\verbbox}} & Lorem1 & Lorem1 \\ \cline{2-3} 
                                   & Lorem2 & Lorem2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]